# Upload file to server PHP

Tags: php

```html
<?php

 if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
  print_r($_FILES['image']);
  
  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");   
  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
   $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }
  if($file_size > 2097152){
  $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }    
  if(empty($errors)==true){
   move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/var/www/tmp/mazat/".$file_name);
   echo "Success";
  }else{
   print_r($errors);
  }
 }
?>
```

Hi I have problem with this php source code above. I am trying to upload file to the server to destination /var/www/tmp/mazat/ where this code is saved. I use this HTML code to upload image file:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" /> 
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

After uploading file it shows message "Success" but the destination doesn't contain uploaded image. Also "print_r" command shows message on screen:
"Array ( [name] => small.png [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 7 [size] => 0 ) Success"

So it looks like it doen't work correctly. Please help me with this stuff guys.

Comment: Does the path exist?

Comment: @Amit Thakur Yes, the path exists. In this location the source code is saved.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if there are any errors, but not if the move was successful.
As the move_uploaded_file returns a boolean you can check:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/var/www/tmp/mazat/".$file_name)){
    echo "Success"; 
}else{
       throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
}
```

As it is usually in this cases, the probly might be related to:

1. Folder permissions
2. Folder location